# Repeat category label on the right side of an AmCharts horizontal dumbbell plot

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

In this CodePen I have a working example of an AmCharts 5 horizontal dumbbell plot:

https://codepen.io/ronmichael/pen/rNqVvMp?editors=1111

You'll see that the category axis label is repeated twice on the left side of the cart. The repeat is generated by the yRenderRight code near the bottom:

```
      var yRendererRight = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
          minGridDistance: 20,
          inside: false
      });

      var yAxisRight = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
          maxDeviation: 0.3,
          categoryField: "group",
          renderer: yRendererRight,
          tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
      }));

      yRendererRight.labels.template.setAll({
          multiLocation: 0.5,
          visible: true // Make the new axis labels visible
      });

      yRendererRight.grid.template.setAll({
          locationY: 1,
          location: 1,
          visible: false // Hide the grid lines of the new Y-axis
      });
```

How do I modify yRenderRight so that the repeat label appears on the right side of the chart?